# Streaming Mp4 video through RTP protocol using Gstreamer in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp, gst-launch

I'm trying to fetch the video file from my local directory,enable the stream from server and capture these frames from my Client side.I have used the following pipelines:

**Server side:**

```
gst-launch -v  filesrc location=/home/gokul/Videos/Econ_TestVideo/radioactive.mp4 ! qtdemux ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=192.168.7.61 port=5000 sync=true


Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VPay:rtpmp4vpay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f528045a1443000001b24c61766335332e33352e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3003638799, clock-base=(uint)1542273545, seqnum-base=(uint)49176
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VPay:rtpmp4vpay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, profile=(string)simple, level=(string)1, codec_data=(buffer)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f528045a1443000001b24c61766335332e33352e30, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)91/3, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VPay:rtpmp4vpay0: timestamp = 1542273545
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VPay:rtpmp4vpay0: seqnum = 49176
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f528045a1443000001b24c61766335332e33352e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3003638799, clock-base=(uint)1542273545, seqnum-base=(uint)49176
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

**Client side:**

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! ffmpegcolorspace !  xvimagesink


Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)1, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

After setting these,i'm not seeing any display(Not even the launch application screen)

To add to the above info,i'm running these command in command line in Ubuntu-12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i will be able to see some video in launch screen.I have used the following pipeline.But the video is not clear.

**SERVER:**

gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc  location=/home/gokul/video.mp4 ! qtdemux name=d ! queue ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink port=5000

**CLIENT:**

gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)243, config=(string)000001b0f3000001b50ee040c0cf0000010000000120008440fa282fa0f0a21f, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)4291479415, clock-base=(uint)4002140493, seqnum-base=(uint)57180" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! xvimagesink sync=false

So can anyone suggest me how to enhance the video image in the client side,by modifying of adding some of the pipeline parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the pipeline for receiver

Sender:

> **gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location = video.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.159 port=5000**

will output CAPS use this caps at the receiver side:

caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96, ssrc=3394826012, timestamp-offset=2215812541, seqnum-offset=46353"

Receiver:

> **gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96, ssrc=3394826012, timestamp-offset=2215812541, seqnum-offset=46353" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false**

hence you will be able to stream and video will be smooth and clean.
In above pipeline if you are using gst-launch-0.10 then replace videoconvert with ffmpegcolorspace

Comment: Does this solution gives widget with video that was sent to networks ?